# Pass DB context between Node.js module functions

Tags: node.js, express, transactions, promise

I'm running Express on Node.js and am wondering how I can effectively pass a single database connection context object between distinct Node modules (think of them sort of like application models).

I'd like to do this to be able to start a database transaction in one model and preserve it across calls to other affected models, for the duration of a single HTTP request.

I've seen people attempt to solve this using per-request database connections exposed as middleware before my route is run (taking from a connection pool, then running another piece of middleware after the routes to return the connection to the pool). That unfortunately means explicitly passing around a context object to all the affected functions, which is inelegant and clunky.

I've also seen people talking about the [continuation-local-storage](https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage) and [AsyncWrap](https://github.com/nodejs/diagnostics/tree/master/tracing/AsyncWrap) modules, but I'm unclear how they can solve my particular problem. I tried working with continuation-local-storage briefly but because I primarily use promises and generators in my code, it wasn't able to pass state back from the `run` method (it simply returns the `context` object passed into its callback).

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
// player-routes.js
router.post('/items/upgrade', wrap(function *(req, res) {
  const result = yield playerItem.upgrade(req.body.itemId);

  res.json();
});

// player-item.js
const playerItem = {
  upgrade: Promise.coroutine(function *(user, itemId) {
    return db.withTransaction(function *(conn) {
      yield db.queryAsync('UPDATE player_items SET level = level + 1 WHERE id = ?', [itemId]);
      yield player.update(user);

      return true;
    });
  })
};

module.exports = playerItem;

// player.js
const player = {
  update(user) {
    return db.queryAsync('UPDATE players SET last_updated_at = NOW() WHERE id = ?', [user.id]);
  })
};

module.exports = player;

// db.js
db.withTransaction = function(genFn) {
  return Promise.using(getTransactionConnection(), conn => {
    return conn.beginTransactionAsync().then(() => {
      const cr = Promise.coroutine(genFn);

      return Promise
        .try(() => cr(conn))
        .then(res => {
          return conn.commitAsync().thenReturn(res);
        }, err => {
          return conn.rollbackAsync()
            .then(() => logger.info('Transaction successfully rolled back'))
            .catch(e => logger.error(e))
            .throw(err);
        });
    });
  });
};
```

A couple of notes here:

1. The `wrap` function is just a little piece of wrapper middleware that allows me to use generators/yield in my routes.
2. The `db` module is also just a small wrapper around the popular `mysql` module, that has been promisified.

What I'd like to do, probably in `db.queryAsync`, is check if there's a `conn` object set on the current context (which I'd set around the `return Promise...` call in `db.withTransaction`). If so, use that connection to do all subsequent database calls until the context goes out of scope.

Unfortunately, wrapping the `return Promise...` call in the CLS namespace code didn't allow me to actually return the promise -- it just returned the `context` object, which is incorrect in my case. It looks like most usages of CLS rely on not actually returning anything from inside the `run` callback. I also looked at cls-bluebird, but that didn't seem to do what I need it to do, either.

Any ideas? I feel like I'm close, but it's just not all hooking up exactly how I need it to.